# My navigation bar isn't displaying properly

Tags: html, css, navigation

I got this navigation bar and the HTML works; I tried to change it up with the CSS by making the position fixed. It currently doesn't display each option only one. I want the position to stay fixed but display the whole menu and not only one part

```
[I circled the part that is messed up][1]
```

```css
div {height:150px;border:1px yellow; background:#ffffff ;}
nav.menu  {
 margin:19px auto; 
 padding:0;
 font-size:.8em;
 text-align:center; 
 }
nav.menu > ul {
 display:block;
 }
nav.menu li {  
 float:left; /* makes menu horizontal */
 list-style-type:none; /* removes default bullets off lists */
 position:fixed; /* position context for child list */
 }
nav.menu ul li a {
 display:block; /* makes link fill line*/
 padding:1em 9em;
 background-clip:padding-box; /* background only under padding, not border */  
 text-align:left;
 text-decoration:none; /* removes link underlining */
 font-family:"Source Sans Pro", helvetica, sans-serif;
 font-style: normal;
 font-weight:600;
 font-size:1.2em;
 color:white;
 -webkit-font-smoothing: antialiased; /* prevents pop of anti-alias change at end of opacity transition */
 }
nav.menu li.choice1 a {
 background:black;
 }
nav.menu li.choice2 a {
 background:black;
 }
nav.menu li.choice3 a {
 background:black;
 }
nav.menu li.choice4 a {
 background:black;
 }
nav.menu li.choice5 a {
 background:black;
 }
nav.menu li:hover > a {
 color:red;
 border-color:#fff;
 border:0;
 }
nav.menu li:last-child a  {
 border-bottom-right-radius:10px;
 }
nav.menu li:first-child a  {border-top-left-radius:10px;}

/* level 2 menus */
nav.menu li ul { 
 opacity:0;  
 visibility:hidden; position:absolute; /* position relative to parent menu */
 width:12em;
 left:0px;   /* aligns left of sub-menu to parent */
 top:100%;  /* aligns bottom of sub-menu to parent */
 }
 .touch nav.menu li ul { /* uses modernizer to only transition opacity of touch devices */ 
 -webkit-transition: 1s opacity; 
    -moz-transition: 1s opacity;
         transition: 1s opacity; 
 }
nav.menu li ul { 
 -webkit-transition: 1s all .2s; 
    -moz-transition: 1s all .2s;
         transition: 1s all .2s; 
 }
nav.menu li:hover > ul {
 opacity:1; /* both properties are transitioned */
 visibility:visible;
 }
nav.menu li li {
 float:none; /* kills inherited float - makes list stack */
 }
nav.menu li li:first-child a {
 border-radius:0;
 }
nav.menu li li:last-child a {
 border-bottom-left-radius:10px;
 }
.no-csstransitions nav.menu li ul { /* for no-transitions browsers */
 visibility:visible; /* overrides transitions version */
 opacity:1;  /* overrides transitions version */
 display:none; /* hides menu if no css transition capability */
 }
.no-csstransitions nav.menu li:hover > ul {
 display:block; /* displays menu when parent hovered */
 }
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC >
 <html>

  <head>
   <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="CSS1.css">
   <link rel="shortcut icon" href="favicon.ico" type="image/x-icon">
   <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
   <title>LeadingEdgeLabs Home</title>
  </head>

  <body>

<!--navigation bar at the top-->

 
   <div>
<nav class="menu">
    <ul>
     <li class="choice1"><a href="home-page.html">Home</a></li>
     <li class="choice2"><a href="photo-gallery.html">Photo gallery</a></li>
     <li class="choice3"><a href="blogs.html">Blogs</a></li>
     <li class="choice4"><a href="contact-us.html">Contact us</a>
<ul>
                    <li><a href="#">Twitter</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">Facebook</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">Email</a></li>
<li><a href="#">Phone</a></li>
<ul></li>


    </ul>
   </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

I see that you added the HTML. This allows me to create this for you....
Check out this rendering in fiddle. (see comment below this answer).

As I stated before (the edit of this answer) the issue is that your nav's natural position is absolute (default for nav, div, etc), and you are setting the menu that holds the *li* items as fixed, which is setting all of of your *li* items to fixed, but within the absolute space of the nav, so they are all going to top:0; left:0 by default.

Setting the outermost parent container that you want fixed, the inner children will adhere to what you are looking for...while the entire nav stays fixed.

You'll notice that I added a bunch of *br* to create a scroll, and it shows that your nav is fixed at the top. I also added a property to the CSS to have each *li* fill the fiddle screen. If you have other styling in your CSS1.css to take care of this, you can just remove the property from that rule.

```css
div {
    height:150px;
    border:1px yellow; 
    background:#ffffff ;
}
nav.menu  {
    position: fixed;
 margin: auto; 
 padding:0;
 font-size:.8em;
 text-align:center; 
 }
nav.menu > ul {
 display:inline; /* Allows li elements to sit side by side */
 }
nav.menu li {  
 float:left; /* makes menu horizontal */
 list-style-type:none; /* removes default bullets off lists */
 position:relative; /* position context for child list */
    text-align:center;
 }
nav.menu ul li a {
 display:inline; /* Changed to INLINE so that it will allow elements side by side*/
 padding:1em 9em;
    background-clip:padding-box;/* background only under padding, not border */  
 text-align:left;
 text-decoration:none; /* removes link underlining */
 font-family:"Source Sans Pro", helvetica, sans-serif;
 font-style: normal;
 font-weight:600;
 font-size:1.2em;
 color:white;
 -webkit-font-smoothing: antialiased; /* prevents pop of anti-alias change at end of opacity transition */
 }
nav.menu li.choice1 a {
 background:black;
 }
nav.menu li.choice2 a {
 background:black;
 }
nav.menu li.choice3 a {
 background:black;
 }
nav.menu li.choice4 a {
 background:black;
 }
nav.menu li.choice5 a {
 background:black;
 }
nav.menu li:hover > a {
 color:red;
 border-color:#fff;
 border:0;
 }
nav.menu li:last-child a  {
 border-bottom-right-radius:10px;
 }
nav.menu li:first-child a  {border-top-left-radius:10px;}

/* level 2 menus */
nav.menu li ul { 
 opacity:0;  
 visibility:hidden; position:absolute; /* position relative to parent menu */
 width:12em;
 left:0px;   /* aligns left of sub-menu to parent */
 top:100%;  /* aligns bottom of sub-menu to parent */
 }
 .touch nav.menu li ul { /* uses modernizer to only transition opacity of touch devices */ 
 -webkit-transition: 1s opacity; 
    -moz-transition: 1s opacity;
         transition: 1s opacity; 
 }
nav.menu li ul { 
 -webkit-transition: 1s all .2s; 
    -moz-transition: 1s all .2s;
         transition: 1s all .2s; 
 }
nav.menu li:hover > ul {
 opacity:1; /* both properties are transitioned */
 visibility:visible;
 }
nav.menu li li {
 float:none; /* kills inherited float - makes list stack */
 }
nav.menu li li:first-child a {
 border-radius:0;
 }
nav.menu li li:last-child a {
 border-bottom-left-radius:10px;
 }
.no-csstransitions nav.menu li ul { /* for no-transitions browsers */
 visibility:visible; /* overrides transitions version */
 opacity:1;  /* overrides transitions version */
 display:none; /* hides menu if no css transition capability */
 }
.no-csstransitions nav.menu li:hover > ul {
 display:block; /* displays menu when parent hovered */
 }
```

```html
<!--navigation bar at the top-->
<div>
<nav class="menu">
    <ul>
     <li class="choice1"><a href="home-page.html">Home</a></li>
     <li class="choice2"><a href="photo-gallery.html">Photo gallery</a></li>
     <li class="choice3"><a href="blogs.html">Blogs</a></li>
     <li class="choice4"><a href="contact-us.html">Contact us</a>
<ul>
                    <li><a href="#">Twitter</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">Facebook</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">Email</a></li>
<li><a href="#">Phone</a></li>
<ul></li>


    </ul>
   </div>
   <br> <br> <br> <br> <br> <br> <br> <br> <br> <br> <br> <br> <br> <br> <br> <br> <br> <br> <br> <br> <br> <br> <br> <br> <br> <br> <br> <br> <br> <br> <br> <br> <br> <br> <br> <br> <br> <br> <br> <br> <br> <br> <br> <br> <br> <br> <br> <br> <br>
```

Comment: For some reason it's not letting me add the link to the [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/lamsharkie/c1mdt4u0/2/) like normal. There you'll find the breakdown, and you can see the display of the code as well.

Comment: Okay thank you but I when I run the code snippet not full screen the options stack on each other; is there anyway to keep them in a straight line?

Comment: Ok, check the edit. That will push things across the top. "Block" elements will not sit side by side, so I changed your 'ul' and 'li' from block to inline... this will allow them to sit on the same row. 

When moving to smaller devices your menu will not look good, however. Have you considered using Bootstrap3 ....at least for your nav? 

www.getboostrap.com  Click on components... navbar (from list on the right) and copy the code to the nav you want... just delete what you don't need, and copy li elements as you need them. Plus, all of the responsive CSS is built into BS3.